# C program, creating processes , PID

Tags: c, pid, qnx

The task is as follows

Write a program that would run another process in memory and leave it running in an infinite loop. When the program is restarted, it must remove the previously started process from memory (you can use kill).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){
    int pid = getpid(); // we find out the PID of the current process and store it in a variable
    FILE *file = fopen("example.txt", "r"); // getting information from a file about a child process
    int filePid = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", filePid);
    fclose(file);
    
    switch (filePid){
        case -1:{ // if there is no child process, then run it and write the PID to a file
            filePid = fork();
            file = fopen("example.txt", "w");
            fprintf(file, "%d", filePid);
            fclose(file);
            break;
        }
        case 0:{ // if this process is a child, then we go into an infinite loop
            for(;;){
                sleep(7); // waiting for seven seconds so that the system is not heavily loaded
            }
            break;
        }
        default:{ // if this program is started again with a child process, then we send a signal to the child process
            kill(filePid, SIGKILL); // we send a signal to the child process so that it ends, and after that we write the information to the file
            file = fopen("example.txt", "w"); // we write information to the file that the child process is missing
            fprintf(file, "%d", -1);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image]
/Yes, I have to do it through the qnx operating system./

the errors are as follows..I'm a little confused with getpid, because I haven't used the pid variable anywhere.
[image]

and another mistake.

[image]

I will be grateful for your help.since I'm a little confused...

**UPD:**

I can't get the value 0

[image]

UPD: how could it execute both cases, i mean "if" and "else" blocks at the same time?

[image]

Comment: where is the fork call?

Comment: @snr in case -1. if I understand you correctly.. filePid = fork();

Comment: `int filePid = 0;` Maybe you should initialize it to `-1` ? And: `fscanf(file, "%d", &filePid);` Also: `fscanf()` returns a value, that you could check.

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of text errors. Copy the errors as text into the question. What is it about "unused variable" that you don't understand? You call `getpid` but never use the result. So what is the intention of making that call? We can't answer that for you as you are the one that wrote that code and you haven't described clearly what the intention of that is.

Comment: @wildplasser so what difference does it make what value I initially assign to fileid?I'm still reading the value from the file. I tried to run the program, but it does not output any messages to the console, and it does not create a text file.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah, I told that I'm a little confused myself.I kind of have to get the pid of the process, of course, but I got confused with the files then... I'm sorry I'm not smart enough than you.But I'm trying to figure it out and so far I can't.

Comment: `getpid` does get the pid of the process. But now what? What do you need/want to do with it? That's the part you haven't explained. If you don't need it or know what to do with it then the simple solution is just to remove that line and that will get rid of the warning. Once/if you have worked out you do need it then you can put it back.

Comment: The problem statement is not clear. But I think what you many need to do is to read the file first before doing the `fork`. If the file contains -1 (or doesn't exist), then you `fork` and save the child pid into the file. If the file contains a non -1 pid then you call `kill` with that pid from the file. So you don't need the current process pid anywhere that I can see and hence no need for the `getpid` call. But may have misunderstood your task as it is not explained very clearly.

Comment: @kaylum if I understand you correctly..but I already read the file at the very beginning, and then only use switch.Look.I wrote to the file at the beginning -1. When the program starts, it generates a fork. after that, a seven-digit number was written to the file. And of course, if I run the program again, I will get into default case. How do I get to 0 case?

Comment: `fscanf(file, "%d", filePid);` -> `fscanf(file, "%d", &filePid);`

Comment: And you need to get rid of the `case 0`. That needs to be checking the `fork` result and not the one you read from the file. That is, you need to move the infinete sleep code to be inside the `case -1` after  the `fork` call.

Comment: @kaylum after this line filePid = fork (); i should add this? if(filePid==0){for(;;){sleep(7)}}
Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes that's right. And in the `else` have the `fprintf` code.

Comment: @kaylum I'm very sorry, I couldn't copy the code from the VM, but I attached a screenshot.I have tested this program, but I never get into an infinite loop. What's wrong?please help me

Comment: re: "I tried to run the program, but it does not output any messages to the console, and it does not create a text file."  Why would you expect any messages?  There is nothing in the code that would write a message.  How are you running the code?  What is the code's working directory.  Add error checking.  eg `if( (file = fopen("example.txt", "r")) == NULL ){ perror("example.txt");}`

Comment: `printf("0")` will likely not write any data until you've written 4096 characters.  With 7 seconds between calls, that will take over 7 hours.  DId you wait that long?  If you want to speed it up, use `printf("0"); fflush(stdout);`  (`putchar` makes more sense here, but the `fflush` is what you need.  That, or perhaps append a newline.)

Comment: What does `filePid` holds? PID of the process you want to create/delete?

Comment: @WilliamPursell okay.now I saw zero in the console. So, I started another process in memory in an infinite loop.Right? But then what process will I remove from memory when I restart the program? The one that was in an infinite loop or the other one (from which I spawned the process)?

Comment: @LinuxGeek the PID of process

Comment: @idk_how And what is the default value of it when you run the program for the first time?

Comment: @LinuxGeek if you mean what is in example.txt file then this is -1

Comment: @idk_how the latest code works fine on my machine, it does print `0`? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @LinuxGeek I added the " fflush(stdout);. ". at the first start, it outputs -1 and 0 ;
the second time - default.  but I still don't understand which process I'm killing when I restart the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could it execute both cases, i mean "if" and "else" blocks at the same time?

You have to have a clear understanding of how `fork` works, when you use `fork` two identical processes are created `parent` and `child` and they run simultaneously, when you say `filePid = fork()` and if the operation is successful then the `parent` process will hold the process id of the child process and `child` process will hold `0`. So here in parent process `filePid == child process ID` and in child process `filePid == 0`.

See `man fork`

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
> and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the
> parent, no child process is created, and errno is set appropriately.

So whatever you put in the `if (filePid == 0)` block will be executed by the child process and whatever you put in the `else` block will be executed by the parent process simultaneously.

[This](https://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) will be helpful if you want to know more about `fork`.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, great. But why does the program write the child pid to the text file , and not the value 0 ?

Comment: Because the `else` block is executed in the parent process and fork returns the child's process id to the parent process. So `filePid` in the `else` block will print the process id of its child. If you write `filePid` into the file in the `if` block then it will write 0 into the file.

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` system call creates a child process and return its pid so once child is created you have two process running same instruction after `fork()` one is checking pid is greater which means its parent which gets child pid and in child context OS will set the pid value to 0 so it will enter condition block intended for child